# How make a custom search on backend in Wordpress without plugin?

Tags: custom-field, admin, wp-admin, search, meta-query

I have a post type called usr_jardin with a custom field called sim_nuip. I would like to get the search to work for the title of the post and also by custom field . I try this but does not work me.

```
function searchfilter($query)
{
    $custom_fields = array("_post_title", "nuip");
    $searchterm = $query->query_vars['s'];
    $query->query_vars['s']="";

    if($searchterm != "")
    {
        $meta_query = array('relation' => 'OR');

        foreach($custom_fields as $cf)
        {
            array_push($meta_query, array('key'=> $cf,'value'=> $searchterm,'compare'=> 'LIKE'));
        }

        $query->set("meta_query", $meta_query);
    }

    if($query->is_search)
    {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'usr_jardin'))
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
add_action('save_post','add_title_custom_field');

function add_title_custom_field($postid){
    update_post_meta($postid, "_post_title", $_POST["post_title"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`pre_get_posts` is an action, not a filter. Change this:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

to this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','searchfilter');
```

You also don't need to return `$query`.

See documentation for pre_get_posts: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: You're right, but I'm pretty sure, these fixes won't make this code to work. It's not pretty, but actually you can use add_filter to Hook an action (at least for now), and of course your action function can return anything (it will be ignored). There is another problem with this code though... Take a look at his query modifications...